# T-SQL: Include a row count as a column for unique rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, unique, rowcount

I have a table, we'll call TableA and contains the following 3 columns with data

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
a      b      c
a      b      c
d      e      f
g      h      i
g      h      i
g      h      i
```

I want to return a record set that looks like this:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Total
a      b      c      2
d      e      f      1
g      h      i      3
```

Duplicate rows are only returned once along with the count of their occurrences. Not sure how to formulate the sql. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Thanks a million!

Answer (score -1):

use subquery .

```
select  a1.col1
        , a1.col2
        , a1.col3
        , (select count(*) 
           from   tableA a2 
           where  a2.col1=col1 
                  and a2.col2=col2 
                  and a2.col3=col3) as count
from    tableA a1
```

Comment: You should be adding a `DISTINCT` clause to make this work but in the end, there really is no need for all this. A simple `GROUP BY` is sufficient.